# How to label a WMS layer from an Online Server, over which I do not have control?

Tags: wms

I have discovered that the Western Australia Dept of Mines and Petroleum [offers](http://geodownloads.dmp.wa.gov.au/datacentre/datacentreDb.asp) WMSs.

On adding these to ArcMap, however, I notice that they do not have labels. For example, this means one must use the identify tool to get the name of a petroleum permit under application. This is a bit dismaying, as I was hoping to use these WMSs in place of downloading the data manually once a month. Without labels in the WMS tiles, I find them less useful for making maps or putting them in ArcReader.

Is there a way to force the labels to appear?

Comment: I do not think you have control over map services as far as turning on or off attribute/labels.